# How to remove JPanel padding in MigLayout?

Tags: java, swing, miglayout

Following situation: when I add a JLabel to a panel, i get unwanted padding/space. How can i remove it? See left side, i want it like the right side of the image shows.

[image]

here's my short test-code, that produces the output shown on the left side of the image above:

```
setLayout(new MigLayout("gapy 0, debug"));
JPanel line1 = new JPanel();
JPanel line2 = new JPanel();;
line1.add(new JLabel("Text 1"));
line2.add(new JLabel("Text 2"));
add(line1, "wrap, align left");
add(line2);
```

Comment: There, you should have enough reputation now to post pictures.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire thanks! i think it should be clearer now with an image...

Comment: contianer.remove(lineX); contianer.revalidate(); contianer.repaint();

Comment: here's the short test-code: --> talking about nothing nor about how  to simulating your posted images

Comment: @mKorbel sorry, i dont get it. i dont want to remove a line, i just want to remove the padding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens because you add labels to `JPanel` which used `FlowLayout` with gaps as default. To fix that you can use next:

```
    JPanel line1 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER,0,0));
    JPanel line2 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
```

[image]